# Moment adding more hours than wanted

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm confused. I'm trying to add one hour to data and time of '2020-03-29T01:00:00.000Z', what I'm getting though is 3'clock same day, not 2'clock.

```
const momentDate = moment('2020-03-29T01:00:00.000Z');
const momentDateWithHourPlus = momentDate.add(1, 'hour');
```

I don't know is it relevant info but in winter time I am in GMT+1, in summer (the above date is summer time) I'm in GMT+2.
Can you explain me what happens here and how can I get exactly 1 hour added?

Comment: try doing the calculation in UTC and convert that to local time, it should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

First I thougth there was only a typo. Instead of "hour" you need "hours" but both will work.
The moment object needs to be called by one of the display methods: .format(), .toDate() or .unix(). 
You might also want to do something like

```
momentDateWithHourPlus.utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')
```

to format it as utc instead of local time.

```
const momentDate = moment('2020-03-29T01:00:00.000Z');
const momentDateWithHourPlus = momentDate.add(1, 'hours');
momentDateWithHourPlus.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is showing the time according to your browser's time zone. Which is why you are seeing 1 extra hour.

Try doing `.toISOString()` and you will get time back as GMT.

```js
const momentDate = moment('2020-03-29T01:00:00.000Z');
const momentDateWithHourPlus = momentDate.add(1, 'hour');
console.log(momentDateWithHourPlus.toISOString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```